# How to extract the type of enumerated value use typescript

Tags: typescript, frontend

```
enum code {
    a = 10,
    b = 20,
    c = "abc"
}
```

Now I have an enum value and I now want to get a union type

```
type IWantGet = 10 | 20 | 'abc'
```

Excuse me, do you have any good solutions?

Comment: You can't do this with enums, but the closest you can get is using a template literal type: \`${code}\`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will become possible in TypeScript 4.8 when the [conversion of string literals to numbers](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/48094) is added.

```
type IWantGet = `${code}` extends infer U 
  ? U extends `${infer S extends number}` 
    ? S
    : U 
  : never

// type IWantGet = "abc" | 10 | 20
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.8.0-beta&ssl=13&ssc=35&pln=7&pc=1#code/KYOwrgtgBAxg9gE2FA3gKCpqBDKBeKARgAYAaDLAI3ygCYyLMYaAibSmFtAXzTQBcAngAdkASQDq2EPwDiwfjQAGAEhTwk3JVGAAPfqAQBnKAEsQAM2AAnKAFUoFAPz2d%20wydUpzV2wGU3AxBjKHAIShstRywoFz9GKAAuVwpkkGAANxs%20AHocqCFRKElpOQVWdk4oAB8iYhq6YiA)

---

For now you can only have a union of string literal types.

```
type IWantGet = `${code}`
// type IWantGet = "10" | "20" | "abc"
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.8.0-beta&ssl=8&ssc=39&pln=7&pc=1#code/KYOwrgtgBAxg9gE2FA3gKCpqBDKBeKARgAYAaDLAI3ygCYyLMYaAibSmFtAXzTQBcAngAdkASQDq2EPwDiwfjQAGAEhTwk3JWgD0OqENFRJ0uQtYkWUAD5QW9K7bYcWQA)

Comment: ... sniped. This doesn't quite work for `enum X { abc = "40" }`.

Comment: @Gerrit0 - why not? Oh I see

Comment: it should give `"40"` but gives `40`